# How to create a vertical progress bar in windows RT

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

Hello I am new to windows RT and I want to create a vertical progress bar in my windows phone 8.1 application. I tried using CompositeTransform Rotation but the orientation remains the same and hence I can't seem to place it at the correct place. Any Ideas on how can I achieve the same without using Margins.
I also checked online everywhere I found to set its orientation property to vertical, I can't seem to find the same in my code
My code is as follows:

```
<ProgressBar VerticalAlignment="Top" Value="50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
<ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
<CompositeTransform Rotation="-90"/>
</ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
</ProgressBar>
```

Comment: Instead, you could draw a hollow rectangle in XAML, and then draw another solid one inside with variable height. The height corresponds to the progress perecentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Could create a custom progress bar or even edit the template. That is a little complicated. As the above answers you could use the two rectangles. If you have too many elements you could use Input Behaviors for a better rendering.

Answer (score 0):

ProgressBar is hard coded to be horizontal.  If you want a vertical one you'll have to build your own.  I haven't done it, but I imagine it would be simple to have a rectangle that you use a scale transform to change its height from 0% to 100% to simulate the progress bar effect.  Alternatively you could use a progress ring.  Another option might be to re-template a slider control which does have an orientation setting.